# google analytics dont show any data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am checking a sample google analytics Android app, but no data is shown in my google analytics account. This is my code:

```
public class ClickTrackerActivity extends Activity {

  GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker; 

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Start your statistics tracking
    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();     
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-39298495-1", 30, this);  

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tracker.trackPageView("/ClickTracker-Main-Screen");  
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    tracker.stopSession();
  }

  public void onClickHighButton(View v) {
    // High button clicked.
    Toast.makeText(ClickTrackerActivity.this, "Chose the High Road", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tracker.trackEvent("Clicks", "Button", "High Road", 0); 
    tracker.dispatch();
  }

  public void onClickLowButton(View v) {
    // Low button clicked.
    Toast.makeText(ClickTrackerActivity.this, "Chose the Low Road", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tracker.trackEvent("Clicks", "Button", "Low Road", 0); 
  }
}
```

What could be the reason for this? Will it take some time to show the data?

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions? If so, you might just need to wait a bit before the data is shown.

Comment: I think it can take 24-48 hours before data is started to get shown in the analytics data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not see live updates. Look at [this](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009219). You will find that google analytics, just like your google play developer console updates once a day around the same time each day.